# waitOn blocking template from loading

Tags: meteor

**When I start the Meteor server and navigate to my default route, I see the AppLoading template inside MainLayout (as expected), but the main template never loads even after the subscription is loaded.**

- I've got a really simple `routes.js` file (below)
- autopublish is still turned on.
- I seeded the db and can confirm in the browser console that the subscription is there, and there are items in my Services collection.

Probably missing something really simple here.

```
/*===================
CONFIGURE DEFAULTS
====================*/

Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate:   'MainLayout',
  loadingTemplate:  'AppLoading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'NotFound'
});

/*===================
CONFIGURE ROUTES
====================*/

Router.route('/', {            // DEFAULT ROUTE
  name: 'main',
  template: 'Main',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('services');
  },
  data: function() {
    return Services.find();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you do not have a publication? The client is waiting for a "ready" notification from the publication and is not receiving it, hence nothing is loaded. Remove autopublish and start writing publications.

The [autopublish package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/autopublish) literally just copies the server DB to the client. You can't subscribe to anything if you do not actually have any publications.

Comment: Thanks. I thought autopublish allowed me to subscribe without publishing. That was my mistake. Autopublish is really autopublish/autosubscribe and if you try to manually subscribe in a waitOn function, it will never return, and that's what was happening to me.